# AVAudioRecorder woes on MacOSX

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, core-audio, avaudiorecorder

I'm attempting to use `AVAudioRecorder` on MacOSX 10.14.x to get audio level readings of an input source -- in this case, the microphone.  As this isn't on iOS, the use of `AVAudioSession` does not apply.  I did enable the microphone in the SandBox settings, as well as double-checking everything in Audio Midi Setup app, with the microphone set to 2ch 24-bit Integer 44.1kHz. I've removed all error checking, but everything *should* be fine (eg. apparent success on all calls to the `recorder` object).  Also, I tried this on another 10.14.x machine with the same result.

**When I run this, all I get is values of -120.0 for both the average and peak power in my callback, even if there is audio.**

**Any idea what I'm doing wrong?**

Note: When I initiate `[recorder prepareToRecord]`, I receive these two error messages:

```
no saved enable hardware sample rate converter preference found
ca_debug_string: inPropertyData == NULL
```

---

```
AVAudioRecorder *recorder;  // instance variable
NSTimer *levelTimer;        // instance variable
```

---

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"/dev/null"];

NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.00],           AVSampleRateKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC], AVFormatIDKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1],                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                          [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh],   AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                         nil];

NSError *error = nil;
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];

[recorder prepareToRecord];
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder record];
levelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.03
                                              target:self
                                            selector:@selector(levelTimerCallback:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
```

---

```
- (void)levelTimerCallback:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [recorder updateMeters];
    float peakPower = [recorder peakPowerForChannel:0];
    float avgPower  = [recorder averagePowerForChannel:0];
}
```